Stuck on start-up
I'm stuck on start-up. Should I reinstall Ubuntu or can I do anything?


press enter and see if you get a login prompt.  If you do, and can remember how to log in, next step would be to determine why the graphics system didn't start.

Tried that. I just have a flashing cursor

I was trying to install unity. I might be better off starting again with the iso

This looks very likely to be a video card driver issue. During bootup of the installation media, you can select "Ubuntu (safe graphics)" instead of  "Try or Install Ubuntu." Are you using an NVidia graphics card? If so, you may have luck by making sure that "Install third-party software for graphics..." is selected during installation, if you didn't the first time. See the link "https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#5-installation-setup"

try press ctrl+alt+f2

Doing that safe graphics thing now. It's an old dell laptop that I wanted as a backup for the kids.

Yeah, pretty sure I had that option selected. It was working fine until I got "fancy" and tried to install unity and did drive stuff I didn't understand. I'll just keep it simple this time and just install apps from the built in app store

If you have luck figuring out exactly what was causing the issue or what you did to correct it, please share that with us.  It is very useful and we are very interested.
